Cloud Custodian tag action does not work with date format for API Gateway
I get the following error using Cloud Custodian's tag action:
2024-06-05 14:39:48,546: custodian.actions:ERROR Exception with tags: {'Creation Date': '05/06/2024 14:32:04'}  Resource Tag Errors {'arn:aws:apigateway:eu-central-1::/apis/abrakadabr': 'InternalServiceException', 'arn:aws:apigateway:eu-central-1::/apis/bbrakadabr': 'InternalServiceException', 'arn:aws:apigateway:eu-central-1::/apis/cbrakadabr': 'InternalServiceException', 'arn:aws:apigateway:eu-central-1::/apis/dbrakadabr': 'InternalServiceException', 'arn:aws:apigateway:eu-central-1::/apis/ebrakadabr': 'InternalServiceException', 'arn:aws:apigateway:eu-central-1::/apis/fbrakadabr': 'InternalServiceException', 'arn:aws:apigateway:eu-central-1::/apis/gbrakadabr': 'InternalServiceException'}

This is my policy.yml:
- name: apigwv2-creation-date-tag-compliance
  resource: apigwv2
  filters:
    - "tag:Creation Date": absent
  actions:
    - type: tag
      tags:
        Creation Date: "05/06/2024 13:35:09"

